# Vagrant Rsync does not sync the folder between host and guest

Tags: ubuntu, docker, vagrant, virtual-machine, rsync

Vagrant Rsync does not work correctly and gives me following error :

```
$  vagrant.exe rsync-auto
==> default: Doing an initial rsync...
==> default: Rsyncing folder: /cygdrive/d/OS/vweb-project/project/web-project/
 => /web-project
==> default: Watching: D:/OS/vweb-project/project/web-project
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/listen-3.0.2/lib/listen/event/queue.rb:1
5: warning: toplevel constant Queue referenced by Thread::Queue
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/listen-3.0.2/lib/listen/event/loop.rb:16
: warning: toplevel constant Queue referenced by Thread::Queue
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/listen-3.0.2/lib/listen/event/loop.rb:38
: warning: toplevel constant Queue referenced by Thread::Queue
```

Here is my vagrant file :

```
$ cat Vagrantfile
ENV["VAGRANT_DETECTED_OS"] = ENV["VAGRANT_DETECTED_OS"].to_s + " cygwin"
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# All Vagrant configuration is done below. The "2" in Vagrant.configure
# configures the configuration version (we support older styles for
# backwards compatibility). Please don't change it unless you know what
# you're doing.
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  config.ssh.insert_key = false

  # The most common configuration options are documented and commented below.
  # For a complete reference, please see the online documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com.

  # Every Vagrant development environment requires a box. You can search for
  # boxes at https://atlas.hashicorp.com/search.
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

  # Disable automatic box update checking. If you disable this, then
  # boxes will only be checked for updates when the user runs
  # `vagrant box outdated`. This is not recommended.
  config.vm.box_check_update = false

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
  # accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8585
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 5432, host: 5432

  # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
  # using a specific IP.
  # config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"

  # Create a public network, which generally matched to bridged network.
  # Bridged networks make the machine appear as another physical device on
  # your network.
  # config.vm.network "public_network"

  # Share an additional folder to the guest VM. The first argument is
  # the path on the host to the actual folder. The second argument is
  # the path on the guest to mount the folder. And the optional third
  # argument is a set of non-required options.
  config.vm.synced_folder "./project/web-project", "/web-project", type: "rsync", rsync__args: ["--verbose", "--rsync-path='sudo rsync'", "--archive", "--delete", "-z"]

  # Provider-specific configuration so you can fine-tune various
  # backing providers for Vagrant. These expose provider-specific options.
  # Example for VirtualBox:
  #
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
    # vb.gui = true

    # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
    vb.memory = 4096
    vb.cpus = 2
  end

  config.ssh.shell = "bash -c 'BASH_ENV=/etc/profile exec bash'"

  # View the documentation for the provider you are using for more
  # information on available options.

  # Define a Vagrant Push strategy for pushing to Atlas. Other push strategies
  # such as FTP and Heroku are also available. See the documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/push/atlas.html for more information.
  # config.push.define "atlas" do |push|
  #   push.app = "YOUR_ATLAS_USERNAME/YOUR_APPLICATION_NAME"
  # end

  # Enable provisioning with a shell script. Additional provisioners such as
  # Puppet, Chef, Ansible, Salt, and Docker are also available. Please see the
  # documentation for more information about their specific syntax and use.
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
     sudo apt-get update
  #   sudo apt-get install -y apache2
  SHELL

  #Docker
  config.vm.provision "docker" do |d|
    #d.build_image "/vagrant/app"
  end
  #Docker-compose
  config.vm.provision :docker_compose, yml: "/web-project/docker-compose.yml", rebuild: true, run: "always"
end
```

I have tried several ways to make it works but nothing seems happen, just information I got this stuff worked yesterday, but I do not know it is do not work again today and I am sure that I do not make any changes on my local environment.

any help will really appreciate.

*I use windows 7 -> cygwin -> vagrant 1.7.4 -> Ubuntu

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be an [issue](https://github.com/guard/listen/issues/330) with the listen gem - upgrading the gem to 3.0.3 would solve the issue (as per the github comments)

As I see from [vagrant latest code](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/master/vagrant.gemspec) they still point to 3.0.2, I think you should open an issue against the project, point them to the gem fix and ask them to upgrade.

In the meantime you can try to make this update and rebuild vagrant if its a possibility for you